# Append a column

Tags: text-processing, sed, columns

I've trawled through here and a few other places to try and find an answer to this, but it seems so stupidly simple that no one has answered it. All I need to do is add a single value in a new column to the end of every line. The closest thing I've found is using `sed -i "s/$/green/" ./test.txt` but this adds the value green to the next line, I need it added as a new column after the current final column

I have a file like this:

```
chr -   xyz ordered_A01 5480    6144
chr -   xyz ordered_A01 5480    58001
```

I need it to look like this:

```
chr -   xyz ordered_A01 5480    6144    green
chr -   xyz ordered_A01 5480    58001   green
```

But instead I get this:

```
chr -   xyz ordered_A01 5480    6144
green
chr -   xyz ordered_A01 5480    5801
green
```

Comment: I forgot to add what the output looks like, I have just added it now. That sed command does create a new line return and not a new column.

Comment: Are you sure your file has standard UNIX <newline> (ASCII 10, 0x0a) line breaks? You could check that using `od -h`.

Answer (score 7):

The sed command you have in your question is actually correct. If you are seeing the result on a new line you either have your terminal set to narrow and are just seeing wrap or there is code included in your actual environment that you are not showing us in this example. It works as is, but there are two issues with it you should be aware of:

1. Using `$` as part of your expression inside a double quoted string is dangerous. Normally that would expand as a bash variable. In this case you got away with it because the `/` character after it is not a valid valuable name, but to avoid this you really should have used single quotes around your expression.
2. If you want to align things as columns, you should probably be including some kind of separator between the end of the line and the value you are adding. A tab might be the simplest way to do this, but you should probably use whatever delimiter you already have between other fields.

Combined, the fixed command might look something like this:

```
sed -i 's/$/\tgreen/' ./test.txt
```

If the results aren't lining up the way you want, you might look into piping your data through `col` to line up the columns.

As far as things you are not showing us, the problem is probably in your data file. Since you mention Wordpad and Excel in a comment. I guess you have a mixed Windows/Unix environment. I suspect the problem is that your data file has garbage non-printing sequences before the end of your lines. You should do something to clean that up. A simple `sed 's/\s*$//'` might be one place to start (strips of all white space characters at the end of the line except the final newline), but a more advanced system like a dos2unix converter might give you better results. If you've got binary garbage in there and the file is supposed to be ASCI text, you could try nuking everything out of range with `tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176'`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I do want it aligned with tabs (as the rest are). I have tried using your command above, the result is that instead of the word green being on a new line, there is now a tab before it on the new line... still the problem of it not being the last column on each line.

Comment: @Jaysred It sounds like you might have funky control characters at the end of the lines in your existing data file. Sed, by itself, is not adding those newlines (if that's what they are). Is this perhaps a data file that has Windows line breaks that have line-feeds to go with the line breaks and they got improperly filtered or reversed at some point?

Comment: Oh, and about the terminal not being wide enough. When I view it in wordpad or excel there is no tab, it is a new line return.

Comment: Good thought Caleb. I got the file from a colleague as a .gff file and copied some of the data to a .txt (in wordpad) so that I could try editing it without destroying the original data. Could this have caused it? if so, how to fix?

Comment: @Jaysred Yes that would do it. And for the love of ponies don't use notepad! That will bite you many different ways as it has no idea what it is doing. At the very least get something like notepad++ or some other real editor that can show you what's actually going on in your files and not silently break them on you.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks so much. Doing sed 's/\s*$//' on the file and then sed 's/$/\tgreen/' worked a treat!

Comment: I'll look into using a better text editor, but at least now I have way around the problem if I come across it again. Thanks to everyone for your help :)

Comment: @Jaysred This whole exercise was just to fix something your non-editor broke. If you don't want to chase your tail again, invest five minutes in downloading a real editor. I'm not a Windows guy but I hear Notepad++ is the [popular alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/notepad-plus-plus/) and the basics of opening, editing, saving, etc. are all the same as what you know already. There will be zero learning curve for doing what you are already doing with notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0 "\tgreen\n"}' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Still no cigar. It still adds the tab and green to the next line.

Comment: @Jaysred works here: does the original file have Windows line endings?

Comment: @jasonwryan should work anyway afaik.

Comment: Possibly, I copied a portion of the data from a .gff file to a .txt so I could trial doing this without destroying the original data by accident.

Comment: @Jaysred Use a decent text editor...

Comment: @jasonwryan do you have a suggestion? I'm still learning all this and have over 500 GB of data to get through and I don't have much time to go about learning new things if it's not currently useful. I've already taught myself some command language, circos, some biopython, bowtie, bismark, a little perl and quite a few propriety packages specific to my work.

Comment: The problem does not appear to be with sed, suggesting a different program without even suggesting _why_ isn't going to solve the problem. Why would awk be a better solution?

Comment: @Caleb: relax. I posted my answer *before* it became apparent that there was more going on with the file endings. It was intended to be an alternative to yours, no better or worse, just different. Also, FWIW, I upvoted your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/$/\tgreen/|x' test.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `\t` tab
3. `x` save and close